# How do I best use CSS to make a page with tall nested elements to be limited to the height of the viewport?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, viewport-units

How do I best enforce a page to be limited to the height of the viewport?  I would like to manage the overflow-y on children elements, but it seems I cannot get the height to constrain--I can only manage a max-height in pixels or a percentage.  I think I need to constrain the height of certain elements to the remaining portion (not a percentage) of the viewport height, but I can't find a way to do that.

(I am using bootstrap, but I suspect the answer isn't bootstrap-centric.)

I thought maybe I could use flex with flex-grow, but that doesn't constrain the height either.  What am I missing?

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column ">
 <div>
 My full-width page title goes here 
 </div>
  <div class="row flex-grow-1">
    <div class="col col-4">
      potentially long content here
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
     main content 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With CSS

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szal/emk3sd6z/12/))

Actual: Page is unlimited height; inner scroll bar is moot; viewport scroll bar is on

Desired: Page uses the whole height of the viewport and no more; inner scroll bar effective; no viewport scroll bar

Comment: Are you looking for [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/tanim_mahbub/9g3w6yd0/11/) ?

Comment: Yes, but that requires knowing the height of the header.  I'd like to put anything in the header and not need to know its height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't married to using bootstrap/flexbox, css grid makes this pretty easy.

#### HTML

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header">
     My full-width page title goes here 
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar">
      sidebar content
    </div>
    <div class="main">
     main content 
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
html, body, .wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header"
    "sidebar main";
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: red;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vexwn5zs/)

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the best bet.  Even works well with a more complicated nesting structure and multiple grids.